# VBA wdNumberGallery set bulletpoints and not numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following function with which i want to apply a specific Style to all numbered elements in my word document:

```
Function SetNumberingStyle()
Dim para As Paragraph, i As Long
  For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    i = i + 1
    If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdNumberGallery Then
        para.Style = ("List Number")
    End If
  Next para
End Function
```

The Problem is that this function sets all the specific Style to all bulletpoints in my word, but i dont know why?
I know that for bulletpoints there is the ListType wdListBullet.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **WdListType enumeration** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlisttype) does not contain a `wdNumberGallery` element. The integer value `wdNumberGallery` you are using is 2, which is equal to `wdListBullet`. So try using `wdListSimpleNumbering` or other values from the WdListType enumeration. Also, your function does not return a value, so you can use Sub instead of Function:

```
Sub SetNumberingStyle()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Then
            para.Style = "List Number"
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but this dont do anything..

Comment: @Andreas Perhaps you have a different type of numbered list. You can place the cursor on the element of the list that you want to set the style, switch to VBE and type in the Immediate pane: `?Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListType` (then press Enter). Displayed number you can use in the condition `If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = <received number> Then` (without <>).

Comment: thank you! That worked. It was "4".
One last error i have is that it keeps them numbering ascending for every paragraph, but i would like every new paragraph to start with numbering at 1. again. I havent found any helpful information. Do you have some remark on this?

Comment: @Andreas 1. A value of 4 corresponds to wdListOutlineNumbering from WdListType enumeration. 2. Try to use VBA Word macro recorder to get appropriate code (it's essentially handy help system)

Comment: What i have found is the attribute "ContinuePreviuosList" so i edited my code:

Comment: `para.Style = "List Number" ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(4).Name = ""
para.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _ ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(4), ContinuePreviousList:= _ False, 
ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _ wdWord10ListBehavior`

  But that still doesnt give the desired result

Comment: @Andreas I think this is an additional question that can be fully described in a new separate question

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I have posted a new question.